# How to find source code of native java function call

Tags: java, android, native

The Android OS has a class called BinderProxy inside android.os.Binder.java. This class has the following function declaration:

```
public native boolean transact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply, int flags) throws RemoteException;
```

I want to find out what code is executed when this function is called.

How will I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look over [here](http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/libs/binder/Binder.cpp), this is the source code of Binder.cpp, which includes this function.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the method called `onTransact` of a corresponding Stub class is called. Basing on the `code` it switches to the corresponding brunch of execution.

Comment: I am new to java, I want to clarify that when you say stub class, you mean the class Binder ?

Comment: What do you want to understand where is the function that is called or how the binder works? If you just try to find where is the code of transact method it is here: frameworks/base/libs/binder/Binder.cpp